# Unable to load HTML before Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascript, and know how can I load html before javascript is executed.

I did check the questions on stackoverflow and tried to implement the solutions given but none worked.

Following is the code of various code that I tried.

1. Wrote script tag before the body ends
2. wrote the javascript code inside a function and called it inside onload of body but it didn't work either.  (Also tried to comment documnet.onload = cal(); and execute).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Age Calculator</title>

</head>
<body onload="cal();">
<h1>Age Calculator</h1>
<p>Enter your age and find how many days you have been alive</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Age.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
//Javascript code
function cal(){
  var age = prompt("How old are you?");
  var days = age * 365.25;
  alert("You are approx " + days + " days");
}

documnet.onload = cal();
```

I want the html to be displayed before user is asked How old are you?

Comment: Always have your browser console open when developing. That way you would see errors like _"Uncaught ReferenceError: documnet is not defined"_ (FYI, it's `document`)

Comment: look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState

Comment: look at fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vks9009/8w24k3xv/. This code will also work if long html code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `prompt` and similar functions like alert *block* the browser - they prevent rendering until the pop-up box has been submitted or canceled.

```html
<h1>Age Calculator</h1>
<p>Enter your age and find how many days you have been alive</p>
<script>
  var age = prompt("How old are you?");
</script>
```

If you want to make sure the HTML displays before the `prompt` comes up, you might use `setTimeout`, giving the browser a chance to paint the HTML before the `prompt` gets called:

```html
<h1>Age Calculator</h1>
<p>Enter your age and find how many days you have been alive</p>
<script>
  setTimeout(() => {
    var age = prompt("How old are you?");
  });
</script>
```

But an even better solution would be to use a proper modal, such as an input box with a `submit` button, which won't *block* the browser. (best to never use `alert`, `prompt`, and `confirm` if at all possible)

Comment: Thank You for your help, but the tutorial which I as seeing had only placed the script tag before body end(</body> and the html was displayed before Javascript.

Browser used by tutor and me is Google Chrome

Could you please advise if it worked for him then why isin't it working for me.
The tutorial might be just a year or two old.

Comment: Was that tutorial also using `prompt`? Can you post its link so we can look at it?

Comment: Yes It was, It is from a paid course online so cannot post a link.

Comment: It must have been doing something *other* than just having a plain `<script>` tag followed by the `prompt`, otherwise you would've seen the same problem you were experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest to read [this](https://eager.io/blog/how-to-decide-when-your-code-should-run/) article. Now, based on the source of this document, the best way (using only Javascript) to wait for the document to fully render before executing some code, will be using a listener on the `load` event of the `window` element, like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // Everything has loaded!
});
```

I have added an image to your code just to test how this approach waits the image to render before prompt to the user:

```html
<h1>Age Calculator</h1>
<p>Enter your age and find how many days you have been alive</p>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500?text=Test+Image">

<script>

function cal()
{
    var age = prompt("How old are you?");
    var days = age * 365.25;
    alert("You are approx " + days + " days");
}

window.addEventListener('load', function()
{
    // Everything has been rendered and loaded!
    cal();
});

</script>
```